# Creating authentication error with Laravel Sanctum

Tags: laravel, authentication, sanctum

I have 2 sections in my website. I used laravel spatie for admin and laravel/sanctum for frontend.
When I use Postman to check front end routes instead showing error "You have not access to this page" redirect to admin login page!

LoginController.php

```
 protected function redirectTo()
    {
        if (!Auth::check()) {
                      return route('admin_login');
        }
    }
```

[image]

But I want to separate Spatie error and Sanctum error

Comment: are you sending the correct header with the request to accept JSON as a response?

Comment: yes content-type:application/json

Comment: that is not the header for accepting JSON back as a response